# SQL query with complicated date conditions

Tags: sql

I have a database table with the following structure:

```
ID      ActiveDate      ActiveQtr      InactiveQtr      Value
------------------------------------------------------------------
1       2004-06-30      2004-06-30     2004-12-31       10
1       2004-08-10      2004-09-30     2004-12-31       200 
2       2004-12-31      2004-12-31     2005-03-31       150
2       2005-01-20      2005-03-31     2005-12-31       60
2       2005-03-31      2005-03-31     2005-12-31       75       
3       2005-04-15      2005-06-30     2007-06-30       100 
2       2005-06-30      2005-06-30     2006-06-30       80
```

ActiveDate can be any date. ActiveQtr is the ActiveDate rolled forward to the next quarter-end date. InactiveQtr is some quarter-end date greater than or equal to ActiveQtr. InactiveQtr doesn't necessarily correspond to the date of the newest entry for an ID and the differences between ActiveQtr and InactiveQtr are not consistent across entries.

What I want is to find, for each ActiveQtr, the sum of all Values that correspond to the most recent entry for each ID that is still active in that quarter.

For this example, the results should look like this

```
ActiveQtr      SUM(Value)
-------------------------
2004-06-30     10
2004-09-30     200 // use more recent entry for ID=1
2004-12-31     350 // entry from ID=1 on 2004-08-10 is still valid
2005-03-31     75  // entry from ID=1 not valid anymore; also only use more recent entry from ID=2
2005-06-30     180
```

I've tried grouping by ActiveQtr, but that doesn't work because I lose entries that are still active in that quarter. I also don't know how to deal with the case where there are multiple entries for an ID that are active for a particular quarter and I need to select the one with the MAX(ActiveDate).

Comment: Your result for 2004-09-30 should be 210, not 200, if I understand correctly.  The 10 is still active.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity. While the 10 is technically still active, it shouldn't be included in the sum because it's not the most recent entry for ID = 1 on that date. I'll edit the post for clarity.

Comment: What would your results be if the data also included a row with the values 

2,2005-03-31,2005-03-31,2005-12-31,70

Comment: @jokeeffe You can assume that (ID, ActiveDate) is unique. (ID, ActiveQtr) is not necessarily unique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There might be simpler ways to do this if you have CTEs and window functions. And this data representation is particularly gnarly, but this works for the supplied data:

```
Select
    x.activeqtr,
    sum(y.value)
From (
    select
        t1.activeqtr,
        t2.id,
        max(t2.activedate) activedate
    from
        test6 t1,
        test6 t2
    Where
        t1.activedate <= t2.inactiveqtr and
        t1.activedate >= t2.activedate
    group by
        t1.activeqtr,
        t2.id
    ) x
        inner join
    test6 y
        on x.activedate = y.activedate and
           x.id = y.id
group by
    x.activeqtr
```

The inner query figures out which `id, ActiveDate` pair to use for each `ActiveQtr`, and the outer query does the summing.

**<kbd>[Example SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c9fdd/1)</kbd>**